# Text following jquery hyperlink is converted to hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery pulling data from Google Calendar.  I have the contents (details) of the calendar event converted into a hyperlink. On the next line I have the location, which is also converted into a hyperlink pointing to google maps.  The problem I have is when entering text in front of the maps link, it turns into a hyperlink for the contents of the line above.

Example-
Info: (hyperlink to details)
Venue: (hyperlink to google map)
The "Venue:" turns into hyperlink of details.

When I place the location in the line before the contents, everything works fine.

Here is my jquery-

```
// event contents
            var contents_url = jQuery.trim(item.content.$t);
            var event_contents = jQuery.trim(item.content.$t);

            // event contents converted to url
            event_contents = "Info: <a href='" + contents_url +"' target='_blank'>" + event_contents.replace(/\n/g, + "</a>");


            // event location 
            var loc_url = item.gd$where[0].valueString;
            var event_loc = item.gd$where[0].valueString;

                var event_loc = "Venue: <a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + loc_url + "' target='_blank'>" + event_loc + "</a>";


            // Render the event
            jQuery("#gcal-events li").last().before(
                "<li>" + event_title + "<ul>"
                + "<li>" + event_start_str + "</li>"
                + "<li>" + event_contents + "</li>"
                + "<li>" + event_loc + "</li>"
                + "</ul>"
                + "</li>"
                + "</br>"
```

I am new with jquery and dont fully understand the .replace(/\n/g, but I'm guessing this is where my problem is.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Seems like the Hyperlink text is not there, hence it  is taking the next text inside the first hyperlink.

Comment: You have a javascript error there...why are you doing a replace for newlines? event_contents.replace(/\n/g, +  "</a>") should be event_contents.replace(/\n/g, "</a>"), but I don't think that's what you want.  If you want to just get rid of the newlines, change it to this: event_contents.replace(/\n/g, "") + "</a>";

Comment: @SoWeLie THANKS!!!! I knew there was something simple.I read somewhere to use the replace for a "just in case", but it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript error there...why are you doing a replace for newlines?

```
event_contents.replace(/\n/g, + "</a>")
```

should be

```
event_contents.replace(/\n/g, "</a>")
```

I don't think that's what you want. If you want to just get rid of the newlines, change it to this:

```
event_contents.replace(/\n/g, "") + "</a>";
```